# vim - Youcomplete me unable to find an appropriate Python library

Tags: python, vim, cmake, clang, youcompleteme

I have followed the instructions from here https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe
and have installed both:

Cmake `sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake`

and Python Headers `sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev`

Then I `cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe` and runned: 
`./install.py --clang-completer` I got:

`Searching Python 2.7 libraries...
ERROR: unable to find an appropriate Python library.`

I then tried 
`python3 install.py --clang-completer` 
but still got:

`Searching Python 3.4 libraries...
ERROR: unable to find an appropriate Python library.`

Does anybody have an idea of what is going on?
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The script isn't finding the path to your python libraries. You might want to make sure you have setuptools installed before you do the following:

The error you're seeing is probably being returned by function FindPythonLibrariesOnLinux() on line 149  in ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/build.py

You can run just the part of script that's causing you problems by creating a file called youcompletemetest.py and fill it with the following code:

```
import sys
import os.path as p
import subprocess
import re

NO_PYTHON_LIBRARY_ERROR = 'ERROR: unable to find an appropriate Python library.'
PY_MAJOR, PY_MINOR = sys.version_info[ 0 : 2 ]
LIBRARY_LDCONFIG_REGEX = re.compile(
'(?P<library>\S+) \(.*\) => (?P<path>\S+)' )

if not ( ( PY_MAJOR == 2 and PY_MINOR >= 6 ) or
            ( PY_MAJOR == 3 and PY_MINOR >= 3 ) or
            PY_MAJOR > 3 ):
    sys.exit( 'ycmd requires Python >= 2.6 or >= 3.3; '
            'your version of Python is ' + sys.version )

def GetPythonNameOnUnix():
    python_name = 'python' + str( PY_MAJOR ) + '.' + str( PY_MINOR )
    # Python 3 has an 'm' suffix on Unix platforms, for instance libpython3.3m.so.
    if PY_MAJOR == 3:
        python_name += 'm' 
    return python_name


def GetStandardPythonLocationsOnUnix( prefix, name ): 
    return ( '{0}/lib/lib{1}'.format( prefix, name ),
            '{0}/include/{1}'.format( prefix, name ) )


def CheckOutput( *popen_args, **kwargs ):
    process = subprocess.Popen( stdout=subprocess.PIPE, *popen_args, **kwargs )
    output, unused_err = process.communicate()
    retcode = process.poll()
    if retcode:
        command = kwargs.get( 'args' )
        if command is None:
            command = popen_args[ 0 ]
        error = subprocess.CalledProcessError( retcode, command )
        error.output = output
        raise error
    return output


def FindPythonLibrariesOnLinux():
    python_name = GetPythonNameOnUnix()
    python_library_root, python_include = GetStandardPythonLocationsOnUnix(
        sys.exec_prefix, python_name )

    python_library = python_library_root + '.so'
    if p.isfile( python_library ):
        return python_library, python_include

    python_library = python_library_root + '.a'
    if p.isfile( python_library ):
        sys.exit( NO_DYNAMIC_PYTHON_ERROR.format( library = python_library,
                                                flag = '--enable-shared' ) )

    # On some distributions (Ubuntu for instance), the Python system library is
    # not installed in its default path: /usr/lib. We use the ldconfig tool to
    # find it.
    python_library = 'lib' + python_name + '.so'
    ldconfig_output = CheckOutput( [ 'ldconfig', '-p' ] ).strip().decode( 'utf8' )
    for line in ldconfig_output.splitlines():
        match = LIBRARY_LDCONFIG_REGEX.search( line )
        if match and match.group( 'library' ) == python_library:
            return match.group( 'path' ), python_include

    sys.exit( NO_PYTHON_LIBRARY_ERROR )

print "\n".join(FindPythonLibrariesOnLinux());
```

You can run that file with:

```
python youcompletemetest.py
```

For me that will output

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so
>
> /usr/include/python2.7

But for you it's not able to locate python. If you know where python is installed you can find that path and replace the entire content of the function called FindPythonLibrariesOnLinux() with an array that contains the locations of your python libraries.

So open the source file:

```
vi ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/build.py
```

Find the function that's not's working:
    /^def\sFindPythonLibrariesOnLinux

Change that function so it only returns the full path to your python libraries (the following in my case):

```
def FindPythonLibrariesOnLinux():
    return ["/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so","/usr/include/python2.7"]
```

Now you will be able to continue with the installation:

```
./install.py --clang-completer
```

Answer (score 1):

While enabling YouCompleteMe on **cygwin**, after installing python-devel package for python 3.4 only statically linked (*.a) version of the library is available:  **libpython3.4.dll.a.**

So I modified:

```
~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/build.py
```

with:

```
def FindPythonLibrariesOnLinux():
  return ["/usr/lib/libpython3.4.dll.a","/usr/include/python3.4"]
```

I'm using: *(CYGWIN_NT-10.0  2.7.0(0.306/5/3) 2017-02-12 13:18 x86_64 Cygwin)*

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can help you => [Issue #2162](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/2162)

```
  sudo apt install python-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

If you install the Windows Python3 version from Python.org and prepend the path (e.g. `c:/Program Files/` path to Windows Python) to the MSYS2/Cygwin environment path *before* the local version of Python, the build script runs without modifying it or uninstalling your local Python.

Basically, the build script seems to need a typical Windows install of Python as it is making some assumptions about the layout?

I'm not sure why this approach works other than perhaps CMake is using the Visual Studio tools and they are operating at the Windows environment level and expecting a typical Windows Python directory structure. The MSYS2 directory structure for Python is much different than the typical Windows Python install.

You can then remove the Windows Python installation path from your MSYS2 path after the build completes.

Comment: should add, then when you invoke the build/install don't use python3, i.e., use "python install.py -all" to invoke the windows python